# How to make responsive designing in WPF without using double scroll bar

Tags: c#, wpf

I have facing issue regarding responsive design using WPF. but I had not find any specific solution yet.I had taken one window WPF page named **MainWindow.xaml** and inner taken MdiContainer child page container. like below:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <mdi:MdiContainer Name="Container" Theme="Generic">
        <mdi:MdiChild Name="ChildWindowContent" WindowState="Maximized" />
    </mdi:MdiContainer>
</ScrollViewer>
```

And after I had binding usercontrol in MdiContainer dynamicaaly named **_CaptureLogsUserControl.xaml** like below:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <DockPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource PanelSaveStyle}" Width="1037" Margin="0,0,15,0" >
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource StackPanelRight}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="17" Margin="10,0,0,0" >
                    <Label x:Name="LabelXMLPath" Width="150" Style="{StaticResource MyLabelStyle}" Content="{Binding .[UIResources.LABEL_SELECT_XMLFILE], FallbackValue={x:Static p:UIResources.LABEL_SELECT_XMLFILE}, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource localisation}}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.795,0.579" Margin="0,6"/>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ColonStyle}" Text=":" />
                    <local:_ToolTipUserControl ToolTip="{Binding Source={StaticResource localisation }, Mode=OneWay, Path=.[UIResources.TOOLTIP_SELECT_CONFIG_FILE]}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

When I run this WPF application at that time I had got double scrollbar. but my scenario I have not need inner scollbar. I had make lots of RND to remove Inner scollbar with responsive design but I had not find any specific solution yet. if any have solution regarding it then please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: So just remove the second scrollbar? You need to post an example with just enough xaml to demonstrate the issue. Your current xaml has way too much  noise and doesn't make any sense (unused Grid rows, Grid columns that don't exist, pointless DockPanels/StackPanels etc)

Comment: Yes. I need to responsive designing  with only one scrollbar. this is possible ? I added extra xaml code for your understanding purpose.my xaml designing showing scenario were I need responsive designing. this way I am added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply below 2 changes:

1. Instead of MdiContainer use ContentControl in MainWindow
2. Remove ScrollViewer control from CaptureLogsUserControl - Due to
   this you are getting double scrollbar